# how to enable checkboxes based on textbox value?

Tags: jquery, html

I a trying to set my group of checkboxes enabled when the value is not empty in my textbox (myinput) otherwise disable the group but it does not work as expected? what am i doing wrong?

html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function enable_cb() {
               if ($(this).val() != "" ) {
                $("input.group1").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $("input.group1").attr("disabled", true);
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="frmChkForm" id="frmChkForm">
    <input id="mytext" type="text" onkeydown="enable_cb(this);" />

    <input type="checkbox" name="chk9[120]" class="group1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk9[140]" class="group1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk9[150]" class="group1">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the input parameter on the method. 'this' is not automagically sent to the method.

```
   function enable_cb(textbox) { 
           if ($(textbox).val() != "" ) { 
            $("input.group1").removeAttr("disabled"); 
        } 
        else { 
            $("input.group1").attr("disabled", true); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Or better yet, assign the event listener from jQuery, and stick to `$(this)`.

Answer (score -2):

have you tried just using `$(".group1")` or `$(".group1 input")`?

Comment: `.group1` would give the exact same result as the current code. `.group1 input` would not work, as it would look for an input that is a child of a `.group1` element. This is entirely unrelated to the problem.